# How to change webhook url of bots business for sending data to different users?

Tags: bots.business

How to change userid in webhook of bots business, so I can post different data to different users?

A normal bots business webhook looks like:

```
https://api.bots.business/v1/bots/185720/new-webhook?&command=BonusWebhook%24%40%25%23%5E&public_user_token=eb0943059fb548e9faf1283b536c594e&user_id=1775114
```

I tried to change `UserId` in that url, but it shows an error.

```
Error : {"errors" : ["You need to sign in or sign up before continuing." ]}
```

How to fix it or any other idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [doc](https://help.bots.business/libs/webhooks-lib):

```
let webhookUrl = Libs.Webhooks.getUrlFor({
  command: "/onWebhook",
  user_id: user.id
})

Bot.inspect(webhookUrl);
```

So you can change user.id in this code.